# How to add or remove rest api array list data

Tags: list, flutter, api, rest

I wanna add some data or string to an array list strings in my rest api data, an it's not working.
I don't know why.
Here is my api data which i got from my api in my local server the json data is below here.

```
 "hotels": [   {
            "image": "http://0.0.0.0:8080/uploads/users/IWpEqUWxUxbWsmIoYfUX/95024057775943965869.jpg",
            "bedPrice": "10",
            "roomPrice": "30",
            "rooms": "50",
            "ac": "yes",
            "address": "kaambo",
            "latitude": "43.0890",
            "laundry": "yes",
            "name": "jaabir",
            "location": "Bosaso",
            "details": "Hosbitaalka Sixa Garoowe waxa ka howlgali doona 23/06/2022 Dr. Ahmed Bashe (abu-shafi) (FCPS MRCS-UK) oo ka socda Hosbitalka Shaafi Muqdisho kuna takhasusay qalliimada LAPAROSCOPY-ga sida Xameetida,Uur-kujirta,Eernada,Burooyinka IWM. Dr-ku wuxuu si joogta ah u imanayaa bil kasta insha allah. Wac: 7747373, 5065444, 5065333.Hosbitaalka Sixa Garoowe waxa ka howlgali doona 23/06/2022 Dr. Ahmed Bashe (abu-shafi) (FCPS MRCS-UK) oo ka socda Hosbitalka Shaafi Muqdisho kuna takhasusay qalliimada LAPAROSCOPY-ga sida Xameetida,Uur-kujirta,Eernada,Burooyinka IWM. Dr-ku wuxuu si joogta ah u imanayaa bil kasta insha allah. Wac: 7747373, 5065444, 5065333.Hosbitaalka Sixa Garoowe waxa ka howlgali doona 23/06/2022 Dr. Ahmed Bashe (abu-shafi) (FCPS MRCS-UK) oo ka socda Hosbitalka Shaafi Muqdisho kuna takhasusay qalliimada LAPAROSCOPY-ga sida Xameetida,Uur-kujirta,Eernada,Burooyinka IWM. Dr-ku wuxuu si joogta ah u imanayaa bil kasta insha allah. Wac: 7747373, 5065444, 5065333.",
            "id": "456",
            "beds": "100",
            "internet": "yes",
            "fastfood": "yes",
            "longitude": "23.0890",
            "images": [
                "http://0.0.0.0:8080/uploads/users/IWpEqUWxUxbWsmIoYfUX/95024057775943965869.jpg",
                "http://0.0.0.0:8080/uploads/users/IWpEqUWxUxbWsmIoYfUX/95024057775943965869.jpg",
                "http://0.0.0.0:8080/uploads/users/IWpEqUWxUxbWsmIoYfUX/95024057775943965869.jpg"
            ],
            "likedUsers": [
                "HftAroebyiUhaKSmsyrc"
            ],
            "adress": "laanta hawada"
        }
]
```

And here is dart code.

```
_likeUser()async{
        String api = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/path=hotels/456";
         // this list from previous page _data['likedUsers'].toList();
         List<String> likes = widget.likedUsers as List<String>;
if(widget.likedUser.contain(widget.currentUser){
          setState((){ _isLiked = false;});
        var likeRemoved = likes.remove(widget.currentUser);
          await http.patch(Uri.parse(api), body: json.encode(<String, Object>{
             "likedUsers": [likeRemoved]
          });
        }else{
        var likeAdded = likes.add(widget.currentUser);
          await http.patch(Uri.parse(api), body: json.encode(<String, Object>{
             "likedUsers": [likeAdded]
          });
        setState((){
        _isLiked = true;
        });
       }
     }
```

Comment: "likedUsers": [likeRemoved] , it's expects array, your likeRemoved itself is array just pass it. "likedUsers": likeRemoved

Comment: If i do so it's showing an error , likeRemoved is a void . which i did not understand what is meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here

```
_likeUser()async{
            String api = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/path=hotels/456";
             // this list from previous page _data['likedUsers'].toList();
             var likes = widget.likedUsers;
    if(widget.likedUser.contain(widget.currentUser){
   // i removed item to list in this here
   var remove = likes.remove(widget.currentUser);
              setState((){ _isLiked = false;});
          
              await http.patch(Uri.parse(api), body: json.encode(<String, Object>{
                 "likedUsers": likes,
              });
            }else{
   // i added item to list in this here
            var add = likes.add(widget.currentUser);
              await http.patch(Uri.parse(api), body: json.encode(<String, Object>{
                 "likedUsers": likes,
              });
            setState((){
            _isLiked = true;
            });
           }
         }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).